# Eliminate one whitespace from python string

Tags: python

Very simple question here. I need to remove one whitespace from my python spring. The line of code in question is

```
print('Total: $',total)
```

which is outputting

```
Total: $ 26
```

I need to remove the space between the $ and 26, so the output reads

```
Total: $26
```

I can't figure out how to do this, can someone please help, probably a simple fix. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Using `f-string` is a simple way to print without whitespaces.

```
print(f'Total: ${total}')
```

There are other ways as well though.

```
print('Total: ${}'.format(total))
```

or

```
print('Total: $%s'%(total))
```

or

```
print('Total: $'+str(total))
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways.

1. Tell `print` not to add the space

```
print('Total: $',total, sep='')  # by default sep = ' '
```

2. [Format a string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

```
print('Total: $ %{}'.format(total))
print('Total: $ %{total}'.format(total=total))
# etc
```

3. f-strings (see @Zero's answer)

In practice you use what's more convenient, because the difference is minuscule. But hypothetically, what difference does it make?

Strings in Python are immutable, i.e. can't be changed. Every time you format a string (`%%`, f-string, `.format()` etc) or concatenate them together, a new string is created - which takes time and memory. Telling `print` not to add space, however, does not require constructing a new string object, and thus is a bit more computationally efficient.

Comment: print('Total: $ %d', total) ???

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use **string concatenation**. You can modify your line of code like this:

```py
print('Total: $' + str(total))
```

Another option is to use **f-string formatting**, which is a more concise and readable approach:

```py
print(f'Total: ${total}')
```